# MySQL trigger and conditional update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a MySQL trigger on `INSERT`: when a new record is inserted in the `wp_posts` table, I want to update `wp_posts.post_author` retrieving the data from other two tables, using two subqueries (I suppose this can be done better).

Anyway, the update should be "conditional", that is the row must be updated only if `wp_posts.post_title` value is "A", "B" or "C". Is this possible?

This is what I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatePostIDonInsert
AFTER INSERT
   ON wp_posts FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code
// ? (pseudo: if wp_posts.post_title IN ("A","B","C") then...)

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 
(SELECT ID from wp_users WHERE user_email = 
(SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID AND meta_key = "_from_email"))

END;
```

Any help is appreciated

[UPDATE] the latest query I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatePostIDonInsert
    BEFORE INSERT
       ON wp_posts FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    IF FIND_IN_SET(NEW.post_title,'General contact,Website contact,Master contact') > 0 AND NEW.post_type ='inbound_com' THEN
    SET NEW.post_author = (SELECT ID from wp_users WHERE user_email = (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = NEW.ID AND meta_key = '_from_email'));

    END IF;

    END;
```

(this works if inserted via PhpMyAdmin trigger section, but without the final END and starting from IF)

Comment: I don't think you can update the same table that is doing the insert trigger, What you can do is have the BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER and modify the value of post_author so the modified value will be inserted together with the other values of your insert query. SET NEW.post_author = <your value here> should return single record if value will come from sub query.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing this out (I'm very new to triggers and I generally don't work with dbs)

Comment: Please note that if you want to access the valueof field that will be inserted you need to use the NEW keyword. i.e. IF FIND_IN_SET(NEW.post_title,'A,B,C,D') > 0 THEN. Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)  function instead

Comment: @Learning why don't you post the entire code of the trigger? That is, I thank you for the comments but I can accept your answer too   :-)

Comment: I forgot to metion that post_type (another column) must contain a certain value, but I suppose I can use FIND_IN_SET twice

Comment: Maybe not related to the error, but in your second condition you don't need a FIND_IN_SET there just AND NEW.post_type= 'inbound_com'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151588/discussion-between-learning-and-3000).

Comment: I can't chat right now, sorry (of course, you're right about FIND_IN_SET, since there's no set at all)   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Instead of triggering the AFTER INSERT take advantage of the BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER

```
    CREATE TRIGGER updatePostIDonInsert
    BEFORE INSERT
       ON wp_posts FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        // add this condition    
    IF FIND_IN_SET(NEW.post_title,'A,B,C') > 0 THEN

            -- variable declarations

            -- trigger code
            SET NEW.post_author = (SELECT ID from wp_users WHERE user_email =
(SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = NEW.ID AND meta_key = "_from_email") LIMIT 1);
        END IF;

    END;
```

You need to make sure that there is only single row that will be returned in your sub query. I'm not familiar with your database structure so I cannot really tell you how you can optimize the sub query for your post_author.

The rest is up to you. You can use FIND_IN_SET whenever you need it.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 (the line is where we set NEW.post_author = ... )

Comment: If I replace " with ', I get: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 8"

Comment: Shouldn't wp_posts.ID be NEW.ID? (just asking)

Comment: Yes it should be NEW.ID

Comment: But it doens't work. I update my post to show you my current query. I removed A, B, C, they were replaced with real values

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with MarianD, but I did try to emulate your select statement with LIMIT 1 after the first close parenthesis and it seems to work fine.  SET @a = (SELECT ID FROM mytable WHERE email = (SELECT emailadd FROM emailaddress WHERE id=1) LIMIT 1);

Comment: I accepted your answer but probably something in my query doesn't work the way I hoped: that is, if I prepare wp_postmeta for a new insert I get an error as if NEW.ID could not be red (and post_author returns NULL: I empirically tried simply hard-coding that value and it returns no error). Anyway, I must rethink anything, I don't like very much the fact that I can't get more detailed errors. Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Is this you need?

Here trigger will only do something if newly inserted post_title is in ("A","B","C")

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatePostIDonInsert
AFTER INSERT
   ON wp_posts FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    // add this condition
    IF (NEW.post_title IN ("A","B","C")) THEN

        -- variable declarations

        -- trigger code
        // ? (pseudo: if wp_posts.post_title IN ("A","B","C") then...)

        UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 
        (SELECT ID from wp_users WHERE user_email = 
        (SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID AND meta_key = "_from_email"))
    END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Problem is it looks like you can't update the same table AFTER INSERT. Check the comment by Learning above